# Como realizar un ScrollReveal con javascript, sin scrollreveal.js y sin jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Lo que intento realizar es un scroll reveal al llegar a cierto punto de mi página web, sin embargo, no quiero hacerlo con jQuery, ¿Por qué?, sencillamente porque creo que hay una mejor forma de realizar lo que quiero hacer, verán principalmente hice lo siguiente en jQuery:

```
class objects {
  constructor(object1, object2, state) {
    this.object1 = object1;
    this.object2 = object2;
    this.state = state;
  }
  get objects1() {
    return this.object1;
  }
  get objects2() {
    return this.object2;
  }
  get state1() {
    return this.state;
  }
}

function altura(objectsAnimated) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var altura = $(`${objectsAnimated.objects1}`).offset().top;

    $(window).on(`scroll`, function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > altura) {
        $(`${objectsAnimated.objects2}`).addClass(`${objectsAnimated.state1}`);
      }
    });
  });
}

let objectsAnimated1 = new objects("#after-images", ".image-1", "active-1");
altura(objectsAnimated1);
let objectsAnimated2 = new objects("#after-images", ".image-2", "active-2");
altura(objectsAnimated2);
let objectsAnimated3 = new objects("#after-images", ".image-3", "active-3");
altura(objectsAnimated3);
let objectsAnimated4 = new objects("#after-images", ".image-4", "active-4");
altura(objectsAnimated4);
```

Después en mi css realice las animaciones correspondientes a el estado activo del 1 al 4, entonces realice lo siguiente:

```
.active-1{animation: entradaImagen1 0.5s 0.6s ease-out forwards;}
.active-2{animation: entradaImagen2 0.5s 0.6s ease-out forwards;}
.active-3{animation: entradaImagen3 0.5s 1s ease-out forwards;}
.active-4{animation: entradaImagen4 0.5s 1s ease-out forwards;}

@keyframes entradaImagen1{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@keyframes entradaImagen2{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(20px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

@keyframes entradaImagen3{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-20px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes entradaImagen4{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(20px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

El html no es nada especial, texto de relleno hasta que pueda hacer suficiente scroll para poder apeciar el efecto.

Ahora mi duda es ¿Puedo realizar el mismo efecto sin jQuery?, ¿Mi codigo realizado con jQuery esta bien hecho?

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es incorrecto porque por cada elemento agregas funciones para escuchar cuando se carga el DOM y cuando hay desplazamiento en la ventana.

También, no es necesario usar plantillas de texto en los selectores si solo contiene la variable, en este caso, solo dificulta la lectura:

```
$(`${objectsAnimated.objects1}`) // No tiene sentido
$(objectsAnimated.objects1) // Esto es exactamente lo mismo
```

Además, revisa los comentarios, tienes error al usar las propiedades:

```
function altura(objectsAnimated) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // Solo estás usando la clase y no ID del contenedor
    // De hecho, sobra una s, la propiedad es object1
    var altura = $(`${objectsAnimated.objects1}`).offset().top;

    $(window).on(`scroll`, function () {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > altura) {
        // Nuevamente sobra la s, la propiedad es object2
        // También sobra el 1 al final, la propiedad es solo state
        $(`${objectsAnimated.objects2}`).addClass(`${objectsAnimated.state1}`);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Es más sencillo crear un arreglo con todos los objetos y tener solo una función para ejecutar cuando haya desplazamiento en la ventana.

```
// Crear objetos
let objectsAnimated1 = new objects("#after-images", ".image-1", "active-1");
let objectsAnimated2 = new objects("#after-images", ".image-2", "active-2");
let objectsAnimated3 = new objects("#after-images", ".image-3", "active-3");
let objectsAnimated4 = new objects("#after-images", ".image-4", "active-4");
// Poner todos los objetos en un arreglo
let animatedObjects = [objectAnimated1, objectAnimated2, objectAnimated3, objectAnimated4];

// Ejecutar cuando haya desplazamiento en la ventana
window.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
    // Recorrer todos los objetos
    animatedObjects.forEach(obj => {
        // Obtener elemento HTML por selector del tipo: "#contenedor .clase"
        let item = document.querySelector(obj.object1 + ' ' + obj.object2);
        // Teniendo el elemento, se toma su posición
        let altura = item.offsetTop;
        // Comparar desplazamiento con posición de elemento
        if(window.scrollTop >= altura) {
            // Agregar clase
            item.classList.add(obj.state);
        }
    });
});
```

Lecturas recomendadas:

- [.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) equivalente de `$('selector')` para un solo elemento; en caso de querer obtener todos los que coincidan, entonces el equivalente es `.querySelectorAll()`
- [.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) equivalente de `$(elemento).scrollTop()`
- [.offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) equivalente de `$(elemento).offset().top()`
- [.classlist.add()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#m%C3%A9todos) equivalente de `$(elemento).addClass()`

Finalmente, si en el contenedor de las imágenes no tiene posición estática, podría ser necesario realizar cálculos adicionales.